# an example of a complete space $X$ and a such mapping $T$ without fixed points & Show that if $X$ is compact then such $T$ has a unique fixed point.

Tags: functional-analysis, contraction-operator

Suppose a mapping $T:X \to X$ has the property: $d(T_x,T_y)< d(x,y)\ \forall x,y \in X $ with $ x\neq y$

a) Give an example of a complete space $X$ and a such mapping $T$ without fixed points

b) Show that if $X$ is compact then such $T$ has a unique fixed point.

For the solution, $T$ is a contraction operator by the description.

For a, the hint is using $f(x) = \ln (e^x+1)$ 
For b, the hint is to consider $\inf d(x,Tx)$

Comment: I can't imagine why you would think that that function would be an example if you don't know how to prove it, unless someone told you. Your post would look a lot less silly if you _said_ it was a hint, instead of saying you thought it would work but don't know how. Similarly for your comment on (b): _Why_ do you think that $\inf$ is relevant?

Comment: Uniqueness is easy. Suppose $x, y$ are distinct fixed points. Then
$d(x, y) = d(Tx, Ty) < d(x, y)$. This is impossible, hence a fixed point (if it exists) has to be unique.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Hint for (a): Apply the Mean Value Theorem to that function you were given.

Hint for (b): Since $d(T(x),T(T(x))) < d(x, T(x))$ if $x\ne T(x)$, you must have $\inf d(x,T(x))=0$. (You should probably explain that a bit.) Now compactness shows (why?) that there exists $x$ with $d(x,T(x))=0$.

Comment: (+1) A hint for (b) is also *Google Banach-Caccioppoli* :D

Answer (score 0):

Another, perhaps easier example for $(a)$ would be $f : \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ given as $$f(x) = \sqrt{1+x^2}$$ for all $x \in \mathbb{R}$.

$f$ has no fixed points:

$$x = \sqrt{1 + x^2} \implies x^2 = 1 + x^2 \implies 0 = 1$$

However, for any $x, y \in \mathbb{R}$, $x \ne y$ holds $\left|f(y) - f(x)\right| < |y - x|$.

Indeed, assume $y > x$:

\begin{align}&\quad\quad\,\,\sqrt{1+y^2} - \sqrt{1+x^2} < y - x\\
&\iff \left(\sqrt{1+y^2} - \sqrt{1+x^2}\right)^2 < \left(y - x\right)^2\\
&\iff 2 + x^2 + y^2 - 2\sqrt{\left(1+x^2\right)\left(1+y^2\right)} < x^2 - 2xy + y^2\\
&\iff 1+xy < \sqrt{\left(1+x^2\right)\left(1+y^2\right)}
\end{align}

This is true by CSB. The strict inequality is because $(1,x)$ and $(1,y)$ are not proportional.

Answer (score 0):

For (a) another example would be $f(x) = x+\dfrac{1}{1+x} $ on $ X = [0,+\infty)$ with the usual metric. It is easy to see that

$$ \lvert f(x) - f(y) \rvert  < \lvert x-y \rvert, \quad \forall x,y \in X, x \neq y $$  (*)

but there is no fixed point (see figure below). The exercise is useful because it shows that to ensure the existence of a fixed point you need a stronger condition (i.e. that the map $f$ is a contraction).

[Example of a non expansive map without a fixed point](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5H39h.png)

(*) Quick proof: Choose wlog $x>y$. Then,

$$ \lvert f(x)-f(y) \rvert = \lvert x-y+\dfrac{1}{1+x}-\dfrac{1}{1+y} \rvert < \lvert x-y \rvert. $$